# What is the rigorous definition of a large cardinal axiom?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I have read in a lot of set theory textbooks about large cardinals and large cardinal axioms. But what is the precise definition of a large cardinal axiom? Is there a rigorous definition of when an axiom $A$ that is not provable from $ZFC$ is a large cardinal axiom?

Answer (score 4):

There is no accepted rigorous definition of "large cardinal axiom," although there are a couple rigorous notions one might consider plausible candidates. See the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155558/what-is-the-definition-of-a-large-cardinal-axiom).